# How to send mails to a segment of a list using New Campaign API (Sendgrid C#)?

Tags: c#, api, sendgrid

Does anyone know how to send mail to a segment of a contact list with Sendgrid New (V3) Campaign API?

The guide only contains the **legacy** Marketing Campaigns, which doesn't work for the latest SendGrid (v3).

https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/campaigns-api/create-a-campaign

Do I use the single-send instead (no campaign API for V3)?
https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/single-sends/create-single-send

**Update:** I tried to create singlesend to send out email:
https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/single-sends/create-single-send

But it always create a DRAFT that appears in my sendgrid dashboard, without actually sending it out. I then tried *Schedule SingleSend* https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/single-sends/schedule-single-send

It works now. So in summary I need to create SingleSend, and then schedule the singlesend (from its ID) with a datetime.

Comment: What error are you getting?  What is the Status code in the response?  Is it 200 OK or a different value?  Are you using HTTPS (secure)?  Was old working code HTTP or HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

Single-sends are the equivalent of the Campaign API for legacy marketing campaigns. You can [send a mail to a segment with a single-send](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/single-sends/create-single-send) with the following JSON data structure:

```json
{ 
  "name": "Single send name",
  "send_to": {
    "segment_ids": ["ENTER_SEGMENT_ID_HERE"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @philnash for your reply. I tried this method, but no matter what I have set in "send_at" (either not have it at all, or a future time), it always create a DRAFT on Sendgrid (without actually sending it out)

Is this the right format for datetime?
DateTime send_time = new DateTime(2022, 2, 1, 20, 15, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var send_time_String = send_time.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss.fffffffzzz");

Comment: The right format for the `send_at` datetime is ISO8601, which you can create with the line `send_time..ToString("yyyyMMddTHH:mm:ssZ")`.